# How to include my DB folder in the web app

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, jetty, war

I have some trouble running my **Spring** based + **Spring Security** web application during authentification (entering the account).
I use **Hibernate** for data access (ORM). Everything is configured well as I think but there is a little problem. When I run server (Jetty) artifact is deployed successfully but in the browser I got following error logs (just the main significant part):

```
Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_2_, user0_.NAME as NAME2_2_, user0_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME3_2_, user0_.PATRONYM as PATRONYM4_2_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as BIRTHDAT5_2_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL6_2_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD7_2_ from PUBLIC.USER user0_ where user0_.EMAIL=?
19:11:38.952 [qtp1500056228-24] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not prepare statement [select user0_.ID as ID1_2_, user0_.NAME as NAME2_2_, user0_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME3_2_, user0_.PATRONYM as PATRONYM4_2_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as BIRTHDAT5_2_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL6_2_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD7_2_ from PUBLIC.USER user0_ where user0_.EMAIL=?]
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1927)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1896)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:964)
    at com.dvdexchange.dao.impl.UserDAOHibernateImpl.getUserByEmail(UserDAOHibernateImpl.java:77)
    at com.dvdexchange.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserByEmail(UserServiceImpl.java:35)
    at com.dvdexchange.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:61)  
....
```

It should be because of I have not included my DB files folder in the output root.
[image: Here is project folder structure in IDEA]

[image: Here is my "Project structrure" settings in IDEA]

As you can see on pictures above - DBStorage folder and it's files are not in the output root. How can I add it in the output root and how should I name it? What about other files and folders? There is also "resource" folder(package) in WEB-INF but it's empty so it is has not been automatically included in in the artifact (output root). What should I do? How should I configurate url of connection in Hibernate.cfg.xml? Now it is configured this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/resources/DBStorage/testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">SA</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->


        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Disk.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Takenitem.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hope you will help me - Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is title related to question?

Comment: Spring and Hibernate use DB to authenticate users. But DBStorage directory is not included in the output root of my web app, that's why it causes NoClassDefFoundException - class can not be initialized.

Comment: @holmis83 I changed the Name of question and I'd like to get some answer!

Comment: @holmis83 I use Maven as build manager and IDE is Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @holmis83 I also added some information. How can I get answer on my question now?